# Why bootstrap dropdown calling window.onfocus

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

When we click on the bootstrap dropdown link, the custom set `window.onfocus` gets called.

Why is Bootstrap calling `window.onfocus` method?

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
  <li data-ng-show="userName" class="">
    <a href="javascript://" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">name<span class="caret"></span></a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
      <li><a href="#">Logout</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

```
window.onfocus = function() {
  alert("window onfocus called");
}
```

[JSFiddle Link](https://jsfiddle.net/ccfbbzfo/2/)

When we click on the menu, alert message will be shown.

Comment: Why do you think it is bootstrap and not just the browser triggering the onfocus because you focused the page?

Comment: @epascarello No, you can check it

Comment: yes bootstrap calling onfocus as when you click in free area in result window in jsfiddle it calls the alert..click ok on alert box..now click again on the free area, no popup... now click on the dropdown , it give the popup

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because Bootstrap triggers a `focus` event on the dropdown anchor that is clicked. This event naturally bubbles up the DOM tree until it is reaches the window, and your functionality is invoked.

You *can* prevent this, by using `event.stopPropagation()`:

```
jQuery(function($){
    $('.dropdown-toggle').focus(function(e){
        e.stopPropagation();
    });
});
```

[**JSFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/ccfbbzfo/4/)

Comment: just curious why bootstrap need to trigger `focus` event on the dropdown

Comment: @user2410148 So that you and I can catch the event if we need to. A normal `select` drop-down would trigger a `focus` event, all Bootstrap attempts to do is mimic this behavior as closely as possible.

Answer (score 1):

Window.onfocus binds itself to the window object, and gets triggered by all focus events, since they bubbles up the DOM tree. The focus event when clicking the dropdown is different then the one when clicking the window. You can see this when viewing the console of [this JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ccfbbzfo/3/).

```
window.onfocus = function(e) {
  console.log(e);
}
```